# IBM DB2 connection issue c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, db2, odbc, oledbconnection

In my Application, two threads trying to open **OLEDB** and **ODBC** connection but one get open and other become in the unresponsive state(hangs while opening a connection). The connection string is OK when try to open connection one by one then it works fine Or make two same connection(ODBC-ODBC or OLEDB-OLEDB) then also works fine but simultaneously with both ODBC and OLEDB, the second call **becomes unresponsive.**

```
 private DbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        if (1 == ConnectionType)
        {
            return new OleDbConnection(DBConnectionString);
        }
        else
        {
            return new OdbcConnection(DBConnectionString);
        }
    }

DbConnection dbConnection = GetConnection();

dbConnection.Open();---> this line becomes unreponsive
```

Comment: Which Db2-client are you using? Is it supplied by IBM, or by Microsoft ? Give exact details.

Comment: This odd behaviour might occur due to shared resources in the code, try putting a lock inside `GetConnection` to see if it helps.

Comment: IBM DB2. Tried putting in the lock but didn't work

Comment: Which IBM-Db2 client? Which version? Which bitness? Which fixpack?  Which operating-system?  (Exact details please).

Comment: v9fp7_winx64_client on OS Window server 2012 R2

Comment: Which fixpack of V9.7 ?  Use the db2level command line to get this information. Is it 32-bit of 64-bit?

Comment: 64bit software  do you think is there any code issue.

Comment: Product identifier           SQL09010
Level identifier             02010107
Level                        DB2 v9.1.0.356
Build level                  s060629
PTF                          NT32
Java development kit (JDK):
Level                        IBM Corporation 1.5.0

Comment: If your Db2-client is "v9.1.0.356 Build level s060629 " , I would say there is no realistic chance of getting that working with multithreaded c#.   That version dates from 2006.  You may also have defects in your own code, but as you don't supply a minimal *complete* example console-app to recreate the issue then you are unlikely to get much help.

Comment: This is a product that has reached EOL. You should first switch to a newer driver (v11.x) and then see if the issue still persists.

Comment: this is the error msg.I am seeing at the event viewer "IC81664: QUIESCE INSTANCE FAILED WITH SQL1371W AND UNQUIESCE INSTANCE FAILED WITH SQL1373W AFTER MS CLUSTER OFFLINE / ONLINE"